# How to deal with "SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead."

Tags: django, django-models

On upgrade to Django 1.9, I now get the warning

```
RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead.
```

I see where the problem arises. I have some custom field definitions, and in them I have `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase`. For example,

```
class DurationField(models.FloatField):

    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    ...
```

If the `__metaclass__` statement is deprecated, what am I supposed to replace it with exactly?

Do I just take it out and add a `from_db_value` method like in the example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects
?

And how are `from_db_value` and `to_python` different? The both seem to convert database data to Python objects?

Answer (score 41):

Yes, you should just remove `__metaclass__` line and add `from_db_value()` and `to_python()`:

```
class DurationField(models.FloatField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        ...

    def to_python(self, value):
        ...
```

As described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#field-api-reference, `to_python(value)` converts the value (can be None, string or object) into the correct Python object.

`from_db_value(value, expression, connection, context)` converts a value as returned by the database to a Python object.

So, both methods return Python objects, but they are used by Django in different situations. `to_python()` is called by deserialization and during the `clean()` method used from forms. `from_db_value()` is called when the data is loaded from the database

Comment: this is very good and comprehensive answer. @mjandrews: why haven't you marked it as a final answer?

Comment: I've found that without the metaclass, the `to_python` isn't always called the same.  For example, if you create a new instance of an object and then try to read the custom field it won't call the methods where with the metaclass it did call the method.

Answer (score 5):

While ozren is right, there is one huge difference, `SubfieldBase` had a really dirty side effect, it always called the `to_python` method on value assignment to the given model field. I have been recently bitten by this while upgrading from Django 1.9 to 1.10.

SEE:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase

Comment: another link might help https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value

Comment: For anyone wondering how the whole solution looks, it is described under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392343/how-do-i-make-a-custom-model-field-call-to-python-when-the-field-is-accessed-imm