# How do I make a custom model Field call to_python when the field is accessed immediately after initialization (not loaded from DB) in Django >=1.10?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-geoposition

After upgrading from Django `1.9` to `1.10`, I've experienced a change in behaviour with a field provided by the django-geolocation package.

This is the change that was made for `1.10` compatibility that broke the behaviour: https://github.com/philippbosch/django-geoposition/commit/689ff1651a858d81b2d82ac02625aae8a125b9c9

Previously, if you initialized a model with a `GeopositionField`, and then immediately accessed that field, you would get back a `Geoposition` object. Now you just get back the string value that you provided at initialization.

How do you achieve the same behaviour with Django `1.10`? Is there another method like `from_db_value` that needs to be overridden to call `to_python`?

Comment: But why use this library at all??

Comment: @e4c5 it gives you a handy google maps widget for your admin pages, and some data validation.

Comment: Maybe it does but you get that with geodjango and lots and lots more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After lots of digging it turns out that in `1.8` the behaviour of custom fields was changed in such a way that `to_python` is no longer called on assignment to a field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase

> The new approach doesn’t call the to_python() method on assignment as was the case with SubfieldBase. If you need that behavior, reimplement the Creator class from Django’s source code in your project.

Here's a Django ticket with some more discussion on this change: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26807

So in order to retain the old behaviour you need to do something like this:

```
class CastOnAssignDescriptor(object):
    """
    A property descriptor which ensures that `field.to_python()` is called on _every_ assignment to the field.
    This used to be provided by the `django.db.models.subclassing.Creator` class, which in turn
    was used by the deprecated-in-Django-1.10 `SubfieldBase` class, hence the reimplementation here.
    """

    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field

    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return obj.__dict__[self.field.name]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.to_python(value)
```

And then add this to the custom field:

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name):
    super(MyField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    setattr(cls, name, CastOnAssignDescriptor(self))
```

Solution was taken from this pull request: https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields/pull/61