# Error: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I run my app django in pycharmn when I execute

```sh
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get

```
@with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, skip_attrs=set([
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'
```

Comment: SubfieldBase is deprecated. Which Django version are you using?

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166085/how-to-deal-with-subfieldbase-has-been-deprecated-use-field-from-db-value-inst

Comment: @shafik django 1.11

Answer (score 0):

SubfieldBase has been deprecated since django 1.10. `django.db.models.fields.subclassing.SubfieldBase`
has been deprecated and will be removed in **Django 1.10.**. It has been replaced with from_db_value().

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please review your answer: The field has either been deprecated or removed in version 1.10, but not both!

Comment: Deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.10